# Is the mean of a continuous random variable $X$ equal to its median?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, means

If we assume $X$ to be a normal distributed random variable, then we can prove than $\Bbb P(X<mean) = \Phi(0) = 0.5$. This is true for any symmetric distribution.

I'm not sure how to prove/disprove it for an asymmetric (around mean) PDF. We're basically trying to see if mean is always the $50\%$ percentile.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematics. Right now, half of your first paragraph has disappeared because you used a < outside of math mode.

Comment: So, for the question I didn't know that $P(X<median) = 0.5$

Comment: $P(X<\text{median}) = 0.5$ is the _definition_ of the median.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$. The mean is $$E[X]=1 ,$$
while the median is $\log(2)$.

Comment: What do u mean by X ~ Exp(1) ? u mean an exponential distribution ?

Comment: @rahdirs Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathsf{P}(X=-1)=\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $\mathsf{P}(X=n)=\frac1{n+1}$.

Then $\mathsf EX=0$ so:$$\mathsf{P}(X<\mathsf EX)=\frac{n}{n+1}$$

Look what happens for a large $n$.

Comment: I believe OP is interested in continuous random variables.

Comment: @user1337 you are right and I must admit that I overlooked that. Nevertheless I will not delete my answer. This because for the topic on its own (median - mean) the distinction continuous/discrete is not relevant in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take the density function $f(x) = 2x$ for $0\le x\le 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Can you calculate median and mean?